# The Bug Genie 'undefined function make_url()'

Tags: php, git, version-control, undefined, undefined-function

> PHP Fatal error: Call to undefined function thebuggenie\core\helpers\make_url() in ../core/helpers/TextParser.php on line 706

This is the error that I keep getting when trying to set up the VCS-integration successfully in The Bug Genie. It is an issue tracker that has VCS (git) integration. The commits can be linked to a project, and with the correct commit-message to the right issue using a git-hook. Then you can view the commit in the issue tracker. Apparently the commit is getting linked to the project, but it doesn't get linked to the issue because of the error. Can anybody help me?

[The source code on GitHub.](https://github.com/thebuggenie/thebuggenie/blob/master/core/helpers/TextParser.php)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found the solution. There appears to be an error in the vcs-integration. Apparently the ui.inc.php-library is not loaded when using the git-hook.

So the temporary solution (until they solve it) is:

At [modules/vcs_integration/Vcs_integration.php](https://github.com/thebuggenie/thebuggenie/blob/27d07543de04f4771205cd3914f56eb8f8d1ea5a/modules/vcs_integration/Vcs_integration.php):226, add: 
`framework\Context::loadLibrary('ui');`

Comment: Note: Support at The Bug Genie has been informed about the error.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i see, [make_url](https://github.com/thebuggenie/thebuggenie/blob/27d07543de04f4771205cd3914f56eb8f8d1ea5a/core/lib/ui.inc.php#L240) function is defined in a global namespace, but is called from namespace `thebuggenie\core\helpers`. So i suppose that's your problem